# i want to use phpmailer.for that i have installed composer,but still autoload file is missing

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer, vendor

I have installed composer successfully.but when i am trying to run code of phpmailer its showing me following error.and also i am unable to find vendor\autoload file and folder in my machine.

---

( ! ) **Warning:**require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such 
    file or directory in C:\wamp\www\mail.php on line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Install Composer from this [link](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe). Then install it to your system. after installation open the command prompt and go to your project dir then use this command

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

and you'll get a vendor directory in your project dir with phpmailer inside it. after that I guess you can figure out how to use it on your own or check the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: i run that path  n see what i have got:        [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Per
  mission denied

Comment: you don't have write access to that directory. check if you have proper write accessibility inside your www folder of wamp